# How would be the JSON is in this example?

Tags: typeahead, typeahead.js

```
$('.example-films .typeahead').typeahead([{name: 'best-picture-winners',
remote: '../data/films/queries/%QUERY.json',prefetch: '../data/films/post_1960.json',
template: '{{value}} – {{year}}',engine: Hogan}]);
```

how would be the JSON file written on this example.
i get this from [typeahead js examples](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/)

Comment: what have you tried?  if you want someone to code it for you, consider hiring one of the developers on the site.

Comment: @Mr.Tiffenbox: It's not clear what you're asking or where you're stuck.  If you just need to see the JSON data being used on that page, surely your browser debugging tools can show that to you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you view the source of the page you can see that there is an attached javascript file at http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/js/examples.js

Here you can view how they bound the typeahead box:

```
 $('.example-films .typeahead').typeahead([
    {
      name: 'best-picture-winners',
      remote: '../data/films/queries/%QUERY.json',
      prefetch: '../data/films/post_1960.json',
      template: '<p><strong>{{value}}</strong> â€“ {{year}}</p>',
      engine: Hogan
    }
  ]);
```

And you will see that you can access prefetch JSON data to see the formatting at http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/data/films/post_1960.json

```
[
  {
    "year": "1961",
    "value": "West Side Story",
    "tokens": [
      "West",
      "Side",
      "Story"
    ]
  },
  {
    "year": "1962",
    "value": "Lawrence of Arabia",
    "tokens": [
      "Lawrence",
      "of",
      "Arabia"
    ]
  },  {
    "year": "2012",
    "value": "Argo",
    "tokens": [
      "Argo"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: I rewrote the question to more closely match the quality of this answer.